# Are there blocked countries in SO?

Tags: support, accounts

I'm asking this just before trying to finish my profile, the only remaining items for me are: "Where are you currently located?" and the assessment, which I already know I can't take, because my country doesn't even appear in the list of possible countries.

So, what happens if I complete my profile and then I lose my account or something? It would really help if someone here had faced this kind of trouble, and already knows what should I do in this case.

Comment: As far as I'm aware SO/SE itself doesn't block anyone. Some used third-party service provider occasionally do, on the other hand. But if I remember correctly that only happens on the currently running survey.

Comment: It happened also in pluralsight.com when I was trying to take an assessment, but it's also a third-party service

Comment: I don't think the country you select could either cause your account to be deleted, or make it harder to recover your account if you forgot your password/etc. I suggest choosing a different (perhaps nearby) country from the list for now. If you give the name of the country then it might be possible to have it added to the list, but I guess only SE staff would be able to do that.

Comment: This is exactly what I am going to do, select a location nearby to mine, I think it is not a good idea to find out for myself if Cuba is on the list or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The location field is *not mandatory* and you don’t even have to state a real place. Plenty of people [picked Mars](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/3631/list-of-users-in-a-given-location?location=Mars), for example. The autocompletion widget is only there to help and encourage you to fill in accurate info. If your location isn’t listed, *just ignore the widget*.

Account login or recovery does not make use of the location field.  Accounts are not blocked or denied access based on their geographical location or the contents of that field.

And [there are plenty of fellow Cubans](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/3631/list-of-users-in-a-given-location?location=Cuba) on SO already, there is no need to worry. :-)

Comment: I better put my location back to Cuba, if Mars counts as a location, I think everything is valid in the location field